# How can this integral be computed?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-calculus

How can this integral be computed?
$$\int _1^b\:\left(x^2-1\right)^pdx$$
Where $p>0$ but different than $1$ and $b\:>\:1$.
When I say computed I mean in any relevant way, may it be a formula, a series, with a computer algorithm etc.
When $p =\frac{1}{2}$ I was able to using trig sub and when $p$ was natural I was able to do so using the binomial theorem. What about other cases?

Comment: Could I get an explaination for that B function? I've found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function but I do not get why the $\frac{1}{b^2}$ in subscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p\in\mathbb{C}$ one could use the extended binomial series
$$(x^2-1)^{p}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{p}{k}x^{2(\alpha - k)}(-1)^{k}\quad (2)$$
to split the integral up. This series converges for all $x\in \mathbb {R}$
with $x>0$ and
$\left|{\tfrac {1}{x}}\right|<1.$

The binomial coefficient is defined for complex values as
$$\binom\alpha z=\frac{1}{(\alpha+1)\,\mathrm B(z+1,\alpha-z+1)}=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)\,\Gamma(\alpha-z+1)},$$
where $\mathrm{B}$ denotes the Euler-Beta function and $\Gamma$ the Gamma-function.

Comment: OP knows this. Next to last sentence.

Comment: @Randall Okay sorry. I did not read it, my fault. Changed it.

Comment: Where is the y?

Comment: should it end up being $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(p,k\right)\left(-1\right)^{k}}{2\left(p-k\right)+1}\left(b^{\left(2\left(p-k\right)+1\right)}-1\right)$?

Comment: Also, I'd be shocked if computing those coefficients was any easier than the original integral.

Comment: @Randalll it is actually fast enough for me!